# How to fix broken flash drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I think I just broke my flash drive - the metal tip bent a little, it did not actually break, but now my computer doesn't recognise it.

It doesn't look damaged at all at first sight, but it does seem to over heat.

What can I do? I'm not really worried about the data inside it, but I'm really bummed about losing a 32gb USB stick like that. :(

Comment: If you aren't concerned about the data inside, you should just move on. Even if you can repair it, the connector will likely not be strong enough and will break again and this time take your data with it.

Answer (score 0):

Bent pins can sometimes be bent back using needle nose pliers or tweezers or any small lever you can find that fits into the sheathing. Work slowly, but be prepared, however, the risk is high the pin will break off and the flash drive will be rendered useless. Good luck!